# Collapse rows based on column 1

Tags: python, perl, awk, text-processing

I want to parse InterProScan results for TopGO R package.

I would like to have a file in a format a bit distant of what I have.

```
# input file (gene_ID  GO_ID1, GO_ID2, GO_ID3, ....)
Q97R95  GO:0004349, GO:0005737, GO:0006561
Q97R95  GO:0004349, GO:0006561
Q97R95  GO:0005737, GO:0006561
Q97R95  GO:0006561


# desired output (removed duplicates and rows collapsed)
Q97R95  GO:0004349,GO:0005737,GO:0006561
```

You can test your tool with the whole data file here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8-ZAuZe8jldMHRsbGgtZmVlZVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you edited your question, removed tag perl, shell and awk. what do you mean? those answers won't be accepted any longer or what?

Comment: Any language is accepted

Comment: Can we rely on the fact that all the lines with the same first column will be adjacent to each other in the input (like they are in your sample)? That lets the code be much more efficient.

Comment: The question is still open. Kent script has a small deviation from the correct result. Is forgetting genes with just one GO term, appart from having duplicated lines. In the above example, forgets 'Q97R95 GO:0006561' line, but result is still fine since GO term '0006561' is also in other lines of gene 'Q97R95'.

Comment: Yes @hobbs, I can sort the input file before. In fact, the large file I'm giving is sorted.

Comment: Seems hobbs solved the dilemma. Kent script had a small deviation from the correct result. Is forgetting genes with just one GO term, appart from having duplicated lines. In the above example, forgets 'Q97R95 GO:0006561' line, but result is still fine since GO term '0006561' is also in other lines of gene 'Q97R95'. – biotech 42 mins ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a, hopefully tidy, Perl solution. It preserves order of keys and values as far as possible, and doesn't keep the whole file contents in memory, only as much as necessary to do the job.

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($prev_key, @seen_values, %seen_values);

while (<>) {
  # Parse the input
  chomp;
  my ($key, $values) = split /\s+/, $_, 2;
  my @values = split /,\s*/, $values;

  # If we have a new key...
  if ($key ne $prev_key) {
    # output the old data, as long as there is some,
    if (@seen_values) {
      print "$prev_key\t", join(", ", @seen_values), "\n";
    }
    # clear it out,
    @seen_values = %seen_values = ();
    # and remember the new key for next time.
    $prev_key = $key;
  }

  # Merge this line's values with previous ones, de-duplicating
  # but preserving order.
  for my $value (@values) {
    push @seen_values, $value unless $seen_values{$value}++;
  }
}

# Output what's left after the last line
if (@seen_values) {
  print "$prev_key\t", join(", ", @seen_values), "\n";
}
```

Comment: Great. 3665 IDs, as in the input.txt file. We are not losing genes, nice.

Comment: @biotech tweaked to make it match more exactly. For input it accepts any kind of whitespace. For output it will use a tab for the first separator, and ", " for the rest.

Comment: Nice, very elegant. In fact, I noticed now that my input file has two spaces as first separator.

Comment: @biotech yeah, that's what I was actually imitating. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of 2-d array of gnu awk:

```
awk -F'[, ]+' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)r[$1][$i]}
         END{for(x in r){
                printf "%s ",x;b=0;
                for(y in r[x]){printf "%s%s",(b?",":""),y;b=1}
                print ""}
         }' file
```

It gives:

```
Q97R95 GO:0005737,GO:0006561,GO:0004349
```

The duplicated fields are removed, however the order was not kept.

Comment: @biotech here I tested, the line ran without any error. do you have gnu awk?

Comment: awk: {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)r[$1][$i]}
awk:                         ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:3:                 for(y in r[x]){printf "%s%s",(b?",":""),y;b=1}
awk: cmd. line:3:                           ^ syntax error

Comment: We need a third tester to replicate possible errors

Comment: For me it works fine with **GNU** awk. I get the syntax error with plain awk. Do a `awk --version` to confirm that you are using GNU awk (e.g., mine returns `GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1`)

Comment: I have GNU Awk 3.1.7

Comment: What is 'plain' awk?

Comment: I'm sure there's a better way to say it, but by "plain" awk I just meant "awk but not gawk" (where gawk == GNU awk).  In your case, however, it's not a question of awk vs. gawk, but the version. I'm pretty sure that true multidimensional arrays were introduced to gawk in version 4. Perhaps @Kent can confirm.

Comment: OK, it's working with GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 . I installed it now in OSX. You are modern people. First time happens to me.